# What are the (relative) performance of the various Power BI Data Sources?

Tags: performance, powerbi

What are the (relative) performance of the various Power BI Data Sources?

Specifically between SharePoint Online, Azure Blob and Azure Data Lake

We're looking at pushing some data into one of these for consumption by Power BI

Answer (score 1):

As these are classes as file sources you will be limited to importing data and to a 1GB dataset sizes, and a refresh frequency of 8 times a day

It will depend on the volume and type, if it is csv files, there is nothing much between Blob and Datalake, it will do a base 1 x 1GB in about 5-8 minutes. That will be for a base read of the data, without any transformations. For multiple files, it will depend on the number

For SharePoint, will it be a list, or documents in a library? After testing about 30,000 items in a list can take about 20-30mins, but again it will depend on the structure, for example how wide it is.

If you are pushing data into something and it is a known structure, use an Azure SQL Database, then you can use direct query, so the data is always up to date.